# How do I enable the https (SSL) support plugin for dillo?

Tags: linux, ssl, plugins, https, fltk

Does anyone know how to enable https support for the Dillo Browser? I want to try logging into Canvas on it (because Dillo is cool) but I am unable to access the login page, and I think the reason is because https support for HTTPS isn't enabled by default. They have a section on it in their FAQs where you can enable a plugin for basic https functionality but I don't really understand the FAQ post.

Their [FAQ page](https://www.dillo.org/FAQ.html) says that:

> First of all, beware that this is a prototype in alpha state. It will only provide for very basic web page retrievals, POST and GET. There is no certificate caching and NO AUTHENTICATION performed.
> It's disabled by default.
> If you want to enable it (e.g. to read forums in https), then use
> `./configure --enable-ssl`
> Then recompile and reinstall.

I don't know where to run the `./configure --enable-ssl` command. I downloaded dillo through `sudo apt install dillo` so I don't really know what recompiling the browser would look like. I also don't know much about the differences between HTTPS and HTTPS and what they mean by 'NO AUTHENTICATION performed'. Even though Dillo is famous for being an extremely barebones browser with the minimal requirements for accessing the internet through a GUI, I am not sure why they wouldn't natively support HTTPS or have a plugin with stronger HTTPS support.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install it manually from : https://www.dillo.org/download.html

Navigate to the folder and run the configurations using :

```
./configure --enable-ssl
```

Then compile using

```
make
```

Then install it using

```
make install
```

(if it doesn't work, you need to provide permissions) so use

```
sudo make install
```

And boom
You are good to go !!